# Java Union array of 2 int arrays using nested loops

Tags: java, arrays, union, nested-loops

I want to create a union array for two integer arrays using nested loops.

This is my  attempt so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class array4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter first array size:");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        int x[] = new int[size];


        System.out.println("Enter first array elements:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            x[i] = input.nextInt();


        }
        System.out.print("Enter second array size:");
        int size2 = input.nextInt();
        int y[] = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            y[i] = input.nextInt();
        }


        System.out.println("Union");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
                if (y[i] != x[z]) {
                    System.out.println(y[i]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By union you mean you just want to combine both arrays? Do you have more requirements? Like, no duplicates? It should be in order? Stuffs like that.

Comment: are you arrays the same size?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear in my question. For union I want to combine both arrays without duplicates. Also the input arrays do not consist of duplicates.

Comment: you have to use set for that. is it mandatory to use array?

Comment: It's just an online course. But it didn't discuss set yet. It said solve this problem using only nested loops and arrays

Comment: Can we assume that arrays are sorted?

Comment: @Silverlight, "Also the input arrays do not consist of duplicates.", what do you mean by this? the user will always input array elements without duplicates? Or it's for us to validate it?

Comment: I mean the user will always input array elements without duplicates

Comment: @Pshemo we can sort the arrays, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that we will print all numbers from second array, and only these numbers from first array which don't exist in second one. So

1. for each element in first array

   1. test if it exist in second array (iterate over elements in second array and set some boolean flag like `exists` to true if `x[i]==y[j]`)
   2. if element doesn't exist in second array print it
2. iterate over elements from second array

   1. and print them

Algorithm can look like

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x.length; i++) {// "<=" is not mistake, 
                                     // in last iteration we print all elements 
                                     // from second array
    boolean exist = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        if (i < x.length) {
            if (x[i] == y[j])
                exist = true;
        } else
            System.out.println(y[j]);
    }
    if (!exist && i < x.length)
        System.out.println(x[i]);
}
```

This algorithm can be probably rewritten to something simpler but I will leave it in this form for now.

Comment: @Silverlight You are welcome, but since you know the idea behind this code you should try to rewrite it without looking at my answer.

Comment: Yeah I already did ;) It actually turned out to be quite simple. I Should have tried harder before asking.

Comment: @Silverlight That is the story of over 90% of questions on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: haha lesson learnt! :)

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of requirements, here is my answer *for now...* just basing on your current code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
        if (y[i] != x[z]) {
            System.out.println(y[i]);
            break; //added break
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was you're printing array elements without duplicate multiple times, to avoid that, you should add a `break` after you print the element with no duplicate.

By the way, your code is just printing the elements on both arrays, I thought you're suppose to combine them? Shouldn't you have a new array that contains both of the elements on the two arrays?

**EDIT 2:**

Add these lines of code after you get the two set of arrays without duplicate:
I also added comments to explain what's happening.

```
System.out.println("Union");
int[] unionArray = new int[size + size2]; //created a new array that will contain two arrays

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //put the first set of int in the new array
    unionArray[i] = x[i];
}

for (int i = size; i < unionArray.length; i++) { //put the second set
    unionArray[i] = y[i-size]; //i = size  : started with the last index of the first array
                               //y[i-size] : we are getting the elements on the second array 
}

for (int i = 0; i < unionArray.length; i++) { //output
    System.out.println(unionArray[i]);            
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: what are size2 and size ? since when we use size for arrays? your code does not make sense at all

Comment: @KickButtowski, `size2` and `size` are variables on his original code.

Comment: and how your answer will give the op the union?

Comment: Because my code is odd and it's just printing the elements on both arrays. I have an loop that prints all the elements of the first array, but even done that way there will still be duplicates

Comment: @Silverlight, I edited my answer. See if it works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately this works exactly like the printing of the elements of the first array + your previous code. It is much neater but still produces duplicate values in the array.

Comment: I think I might have not explained my self clearly. Each array has no duplicate values. But the other array can have a value which is the same as the one in the first array.

Comment: @J.Lucky Thank you so much for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to play with arrays and you don't **need** to use loops - try using a Java collection for that task, that's how most people would probably implement it:

- init collection 1 from array 1
- init collection 2 from array 2
- add collection 2 to collection 1
- convert collection 1 back to an array

That can be a (more or less) neat one-liner.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. However this was actually a nested loops/array exercise for beginners.

Comment: The Java collection framework would require boxing each `int` value as an `Integer`. Not an issue for a toy problem like this, but for large amounts of data the overhead could be significant.

Comment: @Ted: Hmm, while there's probably a core of truth in what you say the way you put it sounds a bit funny. I guess it should be pointed out that _the array is so big that the use of wrapper objects causes performance issues_ is an extreme corner case of all 'non toy' problems. It certainly wasn't an issue whenever I had to merge two arrays so far :)